# How to import files in c++? and how to compile them successfully?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am trying to break my code into multiple files in c++. My main file is base.cpp in which I am trying to import foo.cpp. But it shows the following error during compilation.

**Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "foo()", referenced from:
      _main in base-a3f2f3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64**

My base.cpp file is :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include "foo.h"
using namespace std; 

int main(){
    foo(); 
    cout<<tot<<endl;
    cout<<"bye"<<endl;
}
```

My foo.cpp is :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std ; 

void foo(){
    cout<<"hello world"<<endl; 
}
int tot = 90;
```

My foo.h file is:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
int tot; 
void foo(); 

#endif
```

I use the following command to compile my c++ files successfully : 
g++ -std=c++14 filename.cpp && ./a.out

I use Mac. My code editor is VS Code.

```
My cpp configuaration is as follows : 
{
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: But I am not able to find how to compile my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compile all cpp files:

```
g++ -std=c++14 base.cpp foo.cpp && ./a.out
```

It's not part of the problem but you should avoid `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. It's an implementation defined header

Comment: Thanks. It works. But suppose I want to declare a global variable in foo.cpp and use in base.cpp. How to do this? I am getting duplicate symbol error.

Comment: @SiddharthGoyal `int tot;` is a definition, not a declaration. A global variable can only be defined once. To declare `tot` you can `extern int tot;` in `foo.h` and you have to define it in one cpp file.